# Motivation for blowing-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $X =\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and $Z \to X$ is a closed subscheme given by the ideal $I$. The blowup along $I$ is defined to be $\operatorname{Proj}(A \oplus I \oplus I^2 \oplus\cdots)$ which seems a bit unmotivated to me. I can follow proofs in Hartshorne, but I do not see how one can come up with such a definition. Is there any intuitive approach to it?

Comment: How familiar are you with blowing up? What counts as intuitive to you? Would noticing that this gives the same results as in the original definition of blowing up with varieties in chapter I be enough intuition for you, or are you looking for something else/more?

Comment: @KReiser Indeed, it gives the same as the original definition and it puzzles me. Nevertheless, this is an "a posteriori" explanation and I would love to see some insights for this definition. Definitely it's not a well-posed mathematical question so feel free to ignore it.

Comment: I think this is a very good question.

Comment: One explaination I know is from section 5.2 of Eisenbud's commutative algebra with a view toward algebraic geometry. Maybe it is helpful.